# Get value based on types from Google Geocoding API JSON response with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps, foreach

**I am fetching a JSON response from Google Geocoding API**

whose format is something like this:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Department of Information science and engineering",
               "short_name" : "Department of Information science and engineering",
               "types" : [ "premise" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Gokul",
               "short_name" : "Gokul",
               "types" : [ "political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_1" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Hubballi",
               "short_name" : "Hubballi",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Dharwad",
               "short_name" : "Dharwad",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Karnataka",
               "short_name" : "KA",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "India",
               "short_name" : "IN",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "580030",
               "short_name" : "580030",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
```

**Now I can fetch the attributes in JavaScript using**

```
"Postal Code:" + json.results[0].address_components[6].long_name
```

But from my research I have found that `address_components[6]` might not always be the same data. So I want to fetch value based on types so that I always get the proper data.

**Now I have found a way to do it using php:**

```
foreach ($jsondata["results"] as $result) {
    foreach ($result["address_components"] as $address) {
        if (in_array("sublocality", $address["types"])) {
            $city = $address["long_name"];
        }
    }
}
```

But I cannot figure out how to iterate through each result and get value based on types in JavaScript/JQuery.

Can anyone show me how It's done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the below given code (Pure JavaScript) which implements the same functionality that you implemented using PHP. Run code snippet to see the Output.

```js
var results = [{
  "address_components": [{
    "long_name": "Department of Information science and engineering",
    "short_name": "Department of Information science and engineering",
    "types": ["premise"]
  }, {
    "long_name": "Gokul",
    "short_name": "Gokul",
    "types": ["political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_1"]
  }, {
    "long_name": "Hubballi",
    "short_name": "Hubballi",
    "types": ["locality", "political"]
  }, {
    "long_name": "Dharwad",
    "short_name": "Dharwad",
    "types": ["administrative_area_level_2", "political"]
  }, {
    "long_name": "Karnataka",
    "short_name": "KA",
    "types": ["administrative_area_level_1", "political"]
  }, {
    "long_name": "India",
    "short_name": "IN",
    "types": ["country", "political"]
  }, {
    "long_name": "580030",
    "short_name": "580030",
    "types": ["postal_code"]
  }]
}];

for (result of results) {
  for (address of result.address_components) {
    if (address.types.indexOf("sublocality") != -1) {
      var city = address.long_name;
      alert(city);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's implementation of [`$.each()`](https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjcgOvtguDTAhWQL1AKHTRrCm8QFggnMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fjquery.each%2F&usg=AFQjCNGWEhQCCVLtjc4aKUDQ621LSgRg_w&sig2=tkkmI3_-UsT0JzYTtclQXQ)

```
$.each(jsondata.results, (index, result) => { // <-- ES2016 notation
    $.each(result.address_components, (jndex, address) => {
        if (typeof address.types.sublocality != "undefined"){ // check if value is in an array
            var city = address.long_name;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Javascript**

```js
var x = {
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Department of Information science and engineering",
               "short_name" : "Department of Information science and engineering",
               "types" : [ "premise" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Gokul",
               "short_name" : "Gokul",
               "types" : [ "political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_1" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Hubballi",
               "short_name" : "Hubballi",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Dharwad",
               "short_name" : "Dharwad",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Karnataka",
               "short_name" : "KA",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "India",
               "short_name" : "IN",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "580030",
               "short_name" : "580030",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
      }
  ]
 }
]
}

x.results.forEach(function(elem,index){
   elem[Object.keys(elem)].forEach(function(el,i){
     var city = (el.types.includes('sublocality')) ? el.long_name : 'None';
     console.log(city)
   });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

It is my personal habit to write a function with arguments to get the data I want even from a static source. So here I go.

```
function get_address(json_data, types, short_name) {
// types - the types value that you want to fetch. 
// Eg: "administrative_area_level_2", "country"
// short_name - boolean indicating whether we need short name or long name
// true - short name fetched. false - long name fetched

    short_name = typeof short_name == 'undefined' ? false : short_name //false by default

    results = [];
    for (var i=0; i<json_data.results.length; i++) {
        var ad_comp = json_data.results[i].address_components;
        for (var j=0; j<ad_comp.length; j++) {
            // Check whether ad_comp exists
            if (ad_comp[j].types.indexOf(types) !== -1) {
                results.push(short_name ? ad_comp[j].short_name : ad_comp[j].long_name);
            }
        }
    }

    // Return single match or multiple matches.
    if (results.length == 1) {
        return results[0];
    } else {
        return results;
    }
}

// Call function to get data.
var postal_code = get_address(jsondata, "postal_code");
```

You can replace `for` loops with `$.each` and `indexOf` by `$.inArray` for the jquery version. But the concept is same.

Comment: For the sake of understanding and documentation, you should make sure that this function always returns its data in the same format. So if you name it `getAddress`, it implies that it will return a single address. If you name it `getAddresses` it will return an array of addresses.

Oh and `if(results.length == 0)` then `results[0]` will be `undefined`.

Comment: Agreed. Edited the answer to fix the bug. I concentrated more on the functionality and ignored the naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

```
correct in above get_address answer:
function get_address(json_data, types, short_name) {
// types - the types value that you want to fetch.
// Eg: "administrative_area_level_2", "country"
// short_name - boolean indicating whether we need short name or long name
// true - short name fetched. false - long name fetched

    short_name = typeof short_name == 'undefined' ? false : short_name //false by default

    tmpResults = [];

    $.each(json_data, (index, result) => { // <-- ES2016 notation
        $.each(result.address_components, (jndex, address) => {
            if (address.types.indexOf(types) != -1){ // check if value is in an array
                tmpResults(short_name ? address.short_name : address.long_name);
            }
        });
    });

    // Return single match or multiple matches.
    if (tmpResults.length == 1) {
        return tmpResults[0];
    } else {
        return tmpResults;
    }
}
```